# hanging while entering bootloader menu

Tags: adb, samsung, fastboot, linux, bootloader-lock

Hello every one I want to install ubuntu touch on my galazy W I8550 but I hangs when I use this code `adb reboot bootloader` then it just shws a blak screen witch sayes to continue push up volome bottom or down one to reboot but it just hangs.
DO you help ,e with this?

Comment: I have to say that I cant find it using `fastboot devices` but when I use heimdall `heimdall detect` it can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices don't support fastboot. Hence, the bootloader mode is replaced by the **Download Mode**, in which, by pressing `Volume Up`, you tell your phone to accept incoming data sent from either **Odin** or **Heimdall**.

If your device appears to be stuck in it, just hold the `Power` button until it reboots.

Comment: could you guide me with command orders